# Clipping multiple layers to map series extent using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, clip, map-series

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to create a map series for the first time. I am wanting like 50 layers to only show in they are in the parcel that is being shown during the map series.

The mapbook is for parcels.

Comment: I would suggest using a definition query.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your problem here: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/map-series-can-it-show-only-the-feature-being/td-p/1144738

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).